# Get timestamp from Firebase and convert it into Javascript date object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

[firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED39b.png)

I manage to fetch the timestamp data from firebase and save it into a variable, currentTime.
The timestamp is saved in string type in firebase as shown in the picture.

I want to convert it into Javascript object type.
So, let jsTime = new Timestamp(currentTime);
And I tried to console.log(jsTime.toDate()) but the console shows 'invalid Date'.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You can do it by new Date(currentTime)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following code

```js
let date = new Date(jsTime);
```